# mediacodec encode decode simultaneously?

Tags: android, decode, encode

With the new JB MediaCodec APIs, is it possible to encode and decode AMR simultaneously? I'm getting an illegalstateexception when I try to call dequeueOutputBuffer in the decoder side after I started the encoder. I'm not sure if it's just not possible or something wrong in my code?  Anyone knows?